# Software recommendation for wireless site surveys (WiFi?)

Tags: windows, heatmap

I'd love to find a good piece of software for performing wireless site surveys.  I'm currently looking at [TamoGraph](http://www.tamos.com/products/wifi-site-survey/) but I'm curious to hear if anyone else has used alternate software that might be worth checking out.

The software needs to be able to provide heatmap graphics on a floorplan layout to have maximum effectiveness for our use case.  Signal to Interference ratio and Signal to Noise ratio would also be extremely beneficial.

Comment: [Free WiFi Analyzer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19942/free-wifi-analyzer-for-windows), [Find WiFi Hotspots](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21135/find-wifi-hotspots-on-map-windows-desktop-offline-storage) and [Network Performance Monitoring](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10882/network-performance-monitoring) might help here.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst not too conventional, I'm going to point the answer to another question with similar criteria: [trejder on Free WiFi Analyzer.](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/19943/9311)