# Network performance monitoring

Tags: wifi

An employee at my company is complaining of the WIFI dropping out frequently.

I traveled to the site today and tested the WIFI however, it did not drop out for me.

Is there any good software which will constantly ping a server and log dropouts?

I prefer open source.

Please also suggest any other software which would help identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [InternetConnectivityMonitor](https://code.google.com/p/internetconnectivitymonitor/):

- free and open source (GNU GPL v3)
- Windows, Linux, OS X (Java-based)
- constantly ping a server and log dropouts:

[image]