# Free WiFi analyzer for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, wifi, analytics

I'm using [Wifi Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&hl=en) for my Android-based phone and it works just great. I need a similar tool, *free*, to be used on my Windows-based PC.

These are the ones that I've found so far:

- [inSSIDer 4](http://www.metageek.com/products/inssider/), but it isn't free in any of the versions
- [Xirrus Wi-Fi Inspector](http://www.xirrus.com/free-tools/) is claimed to be free, but it requires you to enter a strange set of data (including company name, size or industry it operates in), before you can download it, so it isn't an option for me (I neither provide false data nor give away such sensitive one to just test a tool)
- [Meraki's WiFi Stumbler](http://tools.meraki.com/stumbler), but it is now discontinued and was [taken over by Cisco](https://meraki.cisco.com/)

Is there any other recommendation, I can take a look at?

Answer (score 2):

[Acrylic WiFi Free](https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/wlan-software/wlan-scanner-acrylic-wifi-free/) sound like a good alternative.

It is free for non comercial usage (has [paid plans](https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/wlan-software/wlan-scanner-acrylic-wifi-free/download-wifi-scanner-windows/), that costs 16.99 USD for one year license or 47.99 USD for lifetime license) and it has direct download link, so I don't have to fill any form before getting it.